# Url redirects you too many times using Cypress Invoke("removeAttr", "target") command

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm using this code to handle new tab and getting this error.
It's displaying chrome-error //chromewebdata/ in url.

Tried for few other example site and it's working fine. I think mine url is redirecting two times that why facing this issue "redirected too many time". How I can handle it?

```
cy.get(".store-list-item__action").contains("a","Log in").eq(0).invoke("removeAttr", 'target').then(newUrl=>{
        cy.wrap(newUrl).click()
    })
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.invoke("removeAttr", 'target')
```

Above Command will work only if system is moving user to same "href" link, in this case after clicking the link systemis redirecting user to another page/link which cypress doesn't support. So cy.request() method can be used for this scenario to validate data.

Answer (score 0):

How about you just use this:

```js
cy.contains('a', 'Log in').invoke("removeAttr", 'target').click()
```

Comment: I'm not sure optimizing the command will avoid the 'too many redirects' issue here.